# Flash WP plugin not working in Chrome and IE9

Tags: flash, internet-explorer, google-chrome, wordpress

I've embed a magazine through a WP plugin (a flash viewer basically) and it doesn't work properly on Chrome and IE9 (drop-down menu elements are covered by the viewer). **The page is: [pastoraluc.cl/dialogos](http://www.pastoraluc.cl/dialogos)**

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5323020/google-chrome-flash-and-z-index-wrong-behvaiour) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6365448/google-chrome-not-respecting-z-index) I found some tips to improve flash behaviour through CSS (z-index and position) and flash wmode option, but CSS didn't work to me and I can't modify flash options in the WP plugin provided by Issuu.

Somebody knows how to fix it? I though in changing the platform to a common HTML object tag inside a div, but in that way the magazine is too different of what I need.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED** editing the return() of **issuu_reader_1** function in wp-issuu.php file. Just adding `wmode="transparent"` in `<embed />` tag, and `<param name="wmode" value="transparent" />` before `</object>` tag.

Now my return is like this:

```
return ( ($showHtmlLink == 'true') ? '<div>' : '') . 
           '<object style="width:' . $width . $unit . ';height:' . $height . $unit. '" ><param name="movie" value="' . $viewerUrl . '?' . $flashVars . '" />' . 
           '<param name="allowfullscreen" value="true"/><param name="menu" value="false"/>' . 
           '<embed src="' . $viewerUrl . '" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" style="width:' . $width . $unit . ';height:' . $height . $unit . '" flashvars="' .
           $flashVars . '" allowfullscreen="true" menu="false" wmode="transparent" /><param name="wmode" value="transparent" /></object>' . 
           ( ($showHtmlLink == 'true') ? ( '<div style="width:' . $width . $unit . ';text-align:left;">' . 
           ( $folderId ? '' : ('<a href="' . $standaloneUrl . '" target="_blank">Open publication</a> - ') ) . 
           'Free <a href="http://issuu.com" target="_blank">publishing</a>' . 
           ( $folderId ? '' : ( $tag ? (' - <a href="' . $moreUrl. '" target="_blank">More ' . urldecode($tag) . '</a>') : '' ) ) . '</div></div>' ) : '');
```